# Access $scope.property outside of a callback function in a controller

Tags: angularjs

Can't think of a better title, sorry.

Please consider the following code -

```
//controller
function ProductCtrl($scope) {
   getCategories(function (result) {
       $scope.category = result.categories[0].name;
   }); // asynchronouse method; getCategories calls uses XHR and returns the result as callback.
}

//view
{{category}}
```

When the view loads in the browser, `getCategories` gets called immediately. How do I make it load on demand, like onLoad on div or something so I can re-use this method somewhere else? Something like, `$scope.getCategories` returns the data I wanted, not on controller load. And how do I use this method in the view? e.g. `<div onload=getCategories()></div>` works?

Another question, the view does not print the `category`. How do I make `$scope.category` available outside of `getCategories`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the view loads in the browser, getCategories gets called immediately. How do I make it load on demand?

Wrap it in a function, and call that function when appropriate:

```
$scope.getCategories = function() {
   getCategories(function (result) { ... }
}
```

> so I can re-use this method somewhere else?

If multiple views need access to the result of getCatetories, you should create a service that stores the result.  Your controllers can then inject that service to get access to it.

> the view does not print the category.

Your AJAX is happening "outside" of Angular, so Angular doesn't know that a callback is being called and that `$scope.category` is being updated.  Simply add `$scope.$apply()` after you update `$scope.category` in your callback and Angular will run a [digest cycle](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime) and update your view.